# Any way to prevent outbound links from being handled by a native app?

Tags: javascript, html

Many mobile apps register themselves as being the way to open certain links. For example, if you have the Medium app installed, then when browsering iOS Safari, if you click on a link to a Medium blog post, it opens in the Medium app.

Is there any way that a website owner can mark up a link in such a way as to force it to open as a web page, not by opening the associated app?

I'm hoping for something like this:

```
<!-- ⚠️ this does not actually work -->
<a href="https://medium.com/..." allowOpenInNativeApp="false">My blog post</a>
```

Comment: Has the answer helped you? (if yes, don't hesitate to upvote it) If not, have you resolved it by yourself? (if yes, don't hesitate to answer your own question)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an url shortener, some of them will

Have you tried

```
<a onclick='window.open("http://yourexternallink.com","_system");'> My blog post</a>
```

Comment: Do you have a reference for _system?

Comment: _system : ' always open in the system web browser '  https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/index.html - it works with apps made with cordova and appartently with a bunch of other cordova-like software. I am not 100% sure about other apps though.